# Multiplying Each Column of a Matrix by a Different Matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, tensors

I have a matrix $A$ of dimension $k \times n$, and also $n$ matrices $B_{i}, i \in [n]$ each of dimension $k \times k$.

I want to define a matrix $C$, $c_{j}$ such that the $j^{th}$ column of $C$ is given as $B_{j} a_{j}$.

I am essentially constructing $C$ by multiplying each column of $A$ by a different matrix.

Is this a standard operation? I was unable to find such a product anywhere. I tried looking at the $B_{i}s$ as a tensor, but still could not find anything.

Comment: well, $C = \mathbf{B}A$, with $ \mathbf{B}=[B_1| \ldots |B_n]$

Comment: If you mean concatenation, then **B** has dimension $k \times nk$, and thus you cannot even multiply **B** and $A$ right? @Surb

Comment: Yes I mean concatenation, I might have done a typo, but I mean, $A\mapsto (B_1a_1,\ldots,B_na_n)$ is certainly linear in $A$ and so can be written in form $\mathbf{B}A$ where $\mathbf{B}$ is well chosen (and depends only on $B_1,\ldots,B_n$). I let you find the correct expression for $\mathbf{B}$ (which I suspect is just a concatenation).

Comment: $\text{vec}^{-1}(\text{diag}(B) \text{vec}(A))$ where diag is block-diagonalization, in other words putting $B_1, B_2,\cdots $ etc after each other along diagonal and fill out with 0s. Vectorization vec is to take column by column and stuff into a long column vector.